# CSS - Absolutely positioned element affected by margin of sibling?

Tags: html, css

I've got a bit of a CSS headscratcher here. It appears I managed to get myself into a position where the absolute position of an element is affected by one of its siblings descendants.

The premise is the following: I have a `<head>` container  with two child elements `<span>` and `<div>`. The `<head>` element is relatively positioned. The `<span>` is absolutely positioned, the `<div>` is relatively positioned. The objective is to have the `<span>` absolutely positioned at top:0px with the `<div>` overlapping it. It appears however that a margin is created by one of the decendats of the `<div>` element.

This has me scratching my head. I'm hopeful that someone can assist.

Here's a [CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgqgRq) example of what I'm talking about.

```css
 body {
   margin: 0;
 }
 h1 {
   font-size: 2em;
   margin: .67em 0;
 }
 p,
 pre {
   margin: 1em 0;
 }
 header {
   height: auto !important;
   min-height: 265px;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   max-height: 638px;
   overflow: visible;
   z-index: 1;
 }
 header > #abstract {
   padding: 0 5%;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 3;
 }
 header > span.featured-img {
   top: 0em;
   min-height: 265px;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <span class="featured-img"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt="featured image" title="{featured image}"/></span>

    <div id="abstract">
      <h1>article header h1</h1>
      <div id="meta">Published:
        <time pubdate datetime="2009-10-09">9th October, 2009</time>by <span class="author"><a href="#" rel="author">John Doe</a></span> in <span "categories">Consectetur</span>
      </div>
      <p class=>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales urna non odio egestas tempor. Nunc vel vehicula ante. Etiam bibendum iaculis libero, eget molestie nisl pharetra in. In semper consequat est, eu porta velit mollis nec.</p>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

I realize that I can make the problem go away by setting the position of the `<div>` to something like fixed or absolute but that causes other flow issues.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: This is probably a margin collapse issue. `overflow:hidden` on the header solves it.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Correct. The margin on the h1 is collapsing with the rest of its ancestors including the header that contains both the absposed element and the h1's parent. Since the absposed element is relative to the header, the collapsed margin indirectly affects the absposed element as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to the `header` element and it should sort it.

Comment: And this way you can retain any margins you have applied to elements like your `h1` and keep the `overflow: visible;` if you need it for any particular reason.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Lighty_46. I have some reading up to do on the why now. :-)

Comment: Nevermind, I found a couple of sites that explained it quite well. First read [this comment](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/why-is-margin-top-causing-the-background-of-a-parent-div-to-move-down/#post-111147) and then read what [block formatting contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) are and how to change them.

Answer (score 0):

The `<h1>` in the div has a top margin. Just get rid of it. `margin:0 0.67em 0`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0 0.67em 0;
}
p,
pre {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
header {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 265px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 638px;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 1;
}
header > #abstract {
  padding: 0 5%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
header > span.featured-img {
  top: 0em;
  min-height: 265px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header> <span class="featured-img"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt="featured image" title="{featured image}"/></span>

  <div id="abstract">
    <h1>article header h1</h1>

    <div id="meta">Published:
      <time pubdate datetime="2009-10-09">9th October, 2009</time>by <span class="author"><a href="#" rel="author">John Doe</a></span> in <span "categories">Consectetur</span>

    </div>
    <p class=>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales urna non odio egestas tempor. Nunc vel vehicula ante. Etiam bibendum iaculis libero, eget molestie nisl pharetra in. In semper consequat est, eu porta velit mollis nec.</p>
  </div>
</header>
```